# why is e.target.value giving error unresolved variable with on-click and working fine with on-change

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**why is e.target.value giving error unresolved variable with on-click and working fine with on-change**

```js
onClick={(e)=>{setInputValue(e.target.value)}} /*unresolved variable for value*/
```

Comment: What type of input are you using for this?

Comment: We need a bit more code. What is the full tag?